# Change the text content of a button after 1 second

Tags: c#, button

I'm implementing a Windows form in c# and if i try to change the text content of a button I find this problem: It shows only the last valorisation of button text.

```
        button.Text ="Content"
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        button.Text = "";
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Because your UI is freezing while you do the sleep, and then updating it - you need to allow it to draw and update while waiting. Such as use a timer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
button.Text ="Content";

Application.DoEvents(); // This will process all UI events currently in message queue

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
button.Text = "";
```

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` will proceed events, but then application will froze  (for a second)

Comment: True, but the OP does not seem to care ATM. Using timers or tasks would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Timer` something like this:

```
  button.Text = "Content";

  Timer timer = new Timer() {
    Interval = 1000,
    Enabled = true 
  };

  timer.Tick += (sender, e) => {
    button.Text = "";

    timer.Dispose();
  };
```

In case you want to *avoid* lambas and *explicit disposing* put the timer on the form.